# Google drive synch from "Drive to PC"

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have created a new file and google drive through the browser.

But I am unable to see the new file on the connected google drive physic PC drive.

Is this not achievable with google drive?

Only one side of synch only work(PC to Google Drive)? Two way syncing is not possible (PC to Google Drive and Google drive to PC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a one way sync (PC to Drive not the other way around). When installing the Google Drive app and do a backup and sync, Google Drive acts as a Cloud backup for any changes to the selected folders you've wanted to backup.

As stated in this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/228989/how-to-use-the-desktop-google-drive-app/):

> The Backup and Sync tool is split up into two main sections:
>
> - **Google Drive**: This performs the same function as the original Google Drive app. You choose what folders to sync from your Google Drive cloud storage, and they’ll appear in a Google Drive folder on your PC. Anything you put into that folder will also sync to Google Drive.
> - **My Computer**: This part is new, and allows you to sync files between your computer and Drive without putting them in the dedicated Google Drive folder. Just pick the folders from your computer you want to sync, and they’ll sync to your cloud storage (though they’ll appear in a separate section of the Google Drive interface, rather than with all your other Drive files.)

Hope this helps.